Removing annotation boxes using QGIS
I'm using QGIS 3.36 Maidenhead and I need to remove annotation boxes that I added but do not want to keep.
I cannot find any option to delete or even edit them, only to add more.  I've tried every way I know of "selecting' them and I cannot select it like you would any other feature.
I've tried the answers to other similar questions to no avail.  Such as, double-clicking, right clicking the box; running a suggested script in the Python plug-in

When mentioning earlier Q&As from this site please always include links to them.
